# .NET Console application using SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am currently evaluating a requirement for a project for which I am considering SignalR. 
Here is a brief:

We want to have a server at our end that can send instructions to a client piece sitting somewhere in the world. The client piece then is supposed to do some local processing and send back a response that the server will show to the user.
The client piece by itself should also be executable and generate the report. 
So we need some .net Code(console) at the client end(across the world) and some code at the hub end(our end). 
Although this is not a ASP.net application I feel like this is a good fit for websocket communication.
I am looking for some guidance on getting a very very basic structure chalked out as I am new to SignalR.

Technologies :
  .net 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guides for setting up your hub and [using the .Net Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client). 
Essentially, the console applications are clients to your hub. Think of the hub as a relay. You can google "signalr console application" and get plenty of information on how to set that up.